# Can't push items into mongodb arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to make a simple social media app using react, express and mongodb.
This is the user model:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        followers: { type: Array, required: false },
        following: { type: Array, required: false },
        likes: { type: Array, required: false},
    },
    { collection: 'users' }
)
```

This is the express server:

```
app.post('/api/follow', async (req, res) => {
    const {token, username} = req.body

    if (token === null)
    {
        return res.json({status: 'error'})
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({username}).lean()
    const _visitor = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET)
    const visitor = await User.findOne({username: _visitor.username})
    if (!user)
    {
        return res.json({status: 'error', error: 'User not found.'})
    }
    if (!visitor)
    {
        return res.json({status: 'error', error: 'User not found.'})
    }

    visitor.following.push(user._id)
    user.followers.push(me._id)

    return res.json({status: 'ok'})
})
```

But when I check the mongodb compass the following and followers arrays are empty.

Comment: You need to _update_ changed documents, call `vistior.save()`, `user.save()`  before the final return: `await Promise.all([visitor.save(), user.save()])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use [`findOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) method to update a value.

Also, if you are updating from two different collections you can use [transactions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html). This is optional but can be useful to avoid inconsitences in your DB.

So your code can be something similar to this:

```
const updateVisitor = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    username: _visitor.username
  },
  {
    $push:{
     following: user._id
    }
  })
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PP9McUR9bgT)

An the same code for `user`:

```
const updateUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    username: username
  },
  {
    $push:{
     followers: me._id
    }
  })
```